# How to run Solver without changing its signature?

Tags: c++

Ok,I am noob learning so pardon me for the simplicity(stupidity) of my ways if any. I have a solver function that i dont want to change that has the format

```
double Solver( double (*FN)(double) )
{
    //return some_solution // based on iterations it does on FN(root finder)
}
```

And the Fn looks like this

```
double FN(double param1)
{
    double param2;
    //..
    double paramn;

    return some_solution
}
```

The predicament is that I want to use the Solver for finding values for different combinations of param2(say an array of different values).
How do I go about doing that without changing the signature of Solver?
Thanks in advance for the help.
Peace!

Comment: Storing `param2` in a global or thread-local variable may be the best option if you can't change `Solver`.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit as to how you would go about doing that using the global approach?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way to do this. The idea is that you can take the parameter out of the function and define a pointer to that parameter.

```
double param2;
double *pparam2 = param2;
double FN(double param1)
{

    //..
    double paramn;

    return some_solution
}
```

and then use a for loop when using solver updating the value of param2 through the pointer everytime as you want like

```
for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
*pparm2= 55+i; //say
 //and here you can use the solver without changing anything and do what //u want.
}
```

Not very elegant but it worked, any better way of doing this?

Comment: Also, `double *pparam2 = param2;` should be `double *pparam2 = &param2;` (if, for some reason, you do need a pointer)

Comment: Yes the correction you made is correct, however the pointer is needed since you run the for loop in main and if you try to change the param2 directly without pointer, it doesn't come to effect.

Comment: but param2 is global.

Comment: Actually these functions are called through instantiating objects of the respective classes they are derived from, so the fix was through pointer.